# Why do Jquery Ajax/Comet page requests return empty responses while I can access them directly?

Tags: jquery, c++, http, nginx, comet

I'm trying to write an application using ajax, with Nginx as frontend, proxying relevant requests to a little application I wrote. All it does is to epoll some sockets and use the file descriptors. Here are some code snippets :

Nginx configuration :

```
upstream cometutils {
  server unix:/tmp/cutil_socket;
}
...
location /test {
  proxy_buffering off;
  proxy_read_timeout 120;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_pass http://cometutils;
}
```

JS code :

```
var kdata="foo=bar";
$.ajax({
  async:true,
  url:"http://127.0.0.1/test",
  data:kdata,
  type:"GET",
  dataType:"text",
  cache:"false",
  success:function(retval)
  {
    alert(retval);
  }
});
```

The relevant C++ code, to give you an idea about what it does :

```
//fd is the file descriptor.
string resp="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\nContent-Type: text/plain\n\nHi there\n";
send(fd,resp.c_str(),resp.length(),0);
resp="sadsadasd\n";
sleep(2);
send(fd,resp.c_str(),resp.length(),0);
close(fd);
```

I'm 100% sure there's no problem with the program, it works perfectly with pretty much anything using a socket communication, including...

...regular page requests ; for instance, typing `http://127.0.0.1/test?blabla=...` will make the browser show `"Hi there!"` text first, then display the second message two seconds later and terminate the connection.

However, the ajax request recieves nothing at all (the response body is simply empty).
It terminates (the `alert()` function is called) right after when it should've received the first message and the server-side `send()` indicates that it has sent all the bytes it should, but the second `send()` returns -1.

I also tried using beforeSend property and plain xmlhttprequest objects to handle onreadystatechange callback directly, but they didn't help at all (readyState never becomes 3, the response is terminated right away).

Any idea on what the reason might be is appreciated.

Comment: Does anything show up in the javascript console or other developer tools?  For example, when using Chrome I look at the Console and Network panels.  This way you can see what the browser sent, what it received, and if there are any javascript issues.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have a Comet-style application where Nginx is used as a frontend proxy for AJAX requests, forwarding them to a C++ application using sockets. The C++ application sends responses asynchronously.

Here are some possible reasons for the issue you're facing:

1. **Buffering in Nginx:**
   Your Nginx configuration includes `proxy_buffering off;`, which disables buffering. This is generally good for streaming, but if there are issues, you might want to try with buffering enabled. Add the following line to your Nginx location block:

   ```
   proxy_buffering on;
   ```
2. **Timing of Responses:**
   Comet-style applications often rely on the timing of responses. Make sure that the server-side code is sending responses when expected. You already mentioned that regular page requests work, so the server-side code might be functioning correctly.
3. **AJAX Timeout:**
   The default timeout for AJAX requests might be too short for your long-polling Comet application. You've set `proxy_read_timeout 120;` in Nginx, but you might want to increase the timeout for the AJAX request as well:

   ```js
   timeout: 120000,  // Set the AJAX timeout to 120 seconds
   ```
4. **Error Handling:**
   Include an error callback in your AJAX request to capture any errors:

   ```js
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log('AJAX Error:', textStatus, errorThrown);
   }
   ```

   Check the browser console for error messages.
5. **Inspecting Network Traffic:**
   Use browser developer tools to inspect network traffic. Look at the headers and response content. Check if there are any errors or unexpected behavior.
6. **Content-Type Header:**
   Ensure that your C++ application sets the `Content-Type` header appropriately. In your code, you are setting it to `text/plain`, but make sure this matches the actual content.

   ```cpp
   string resp = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/plain\n\nHi there\n";
   ```
7. **Testing without Nginx:**
   To isolate the issue, you might want to test your C++ server directly without Nginx in the middle. This will help you determine if the problem is related to the Nginx configuration or the C++ server.
8. **Nginx Error Logs:**
   Check Nginx error logs (`/var/log/nginx/error.log`) for any error messages related to the proxying of requests.

By addressing these points and potentially adjusting your configurations, you should be able to identify and resolve the issue with your AJAX requests not receiving the expected responses in your Comet application.